# Object moving the wrong direction

Tags: velocity, direction

```
public Cars(int x, int y)
    {
        xVel = ran.nextInt (5)+2;

        if (ran.nextInt(5)+2%2 == 0)

        {
            xVel*=-1;
        }

        rec = new Rectangle (x, y, 30, 30);
        xPosition = x;
        yPosition = y;
    }
```

So I'm making a game where all the "cars" move right but once in a while a car will move left instead.  How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Check your Operator Precedence: `ran.nextInt(5)+2%2` evaluates "2%2" first (which is always `0`). However, this cannot be the problem, as the test `ran.nextInt(5)` still ought to return `0` once in a while.